# Comments in Team City Artifact Paths Field

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Is it possible to add comments into the Artifact paths field in Team City?  What format should I use?  I'd like for the next guy to be able to quickly understand what is going on and why.

Comment: Do you want to add comment/tool tip kind of thing against artifacts files?. Generally naming file appropriately give hints to what it signifies. Current support is only as said in this page I think: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths

Comment: Nothing as fancy as tooltips, just inline comments.  Simple stuff like: //Put all configs here, correct version will be selected at deploy time

Comment: As far as I know, you can't, there is option to create custom plugin which will extend TeamCity UI, but out of box the there is no such option. If you need some kind additional information for artifacts I suggest you add some sort of txt file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use anything that doesn't match a file. It will show up as warning in the build log (matching artifacts not found), but do no harm otherwise.

I use a hash to start comments, for example:

```
# Collect all DLLs from unicorn
unicorn/**/*.dll
```